# python 3.5.0 ::: printing dates and times

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

So I used datetime module to print dates and made it so far.

However I cannot print times...

Every time I run:

```
currentTime = datetime.time()
print (currentTime)
```

The result is:

```
00:00:00
```

I tried:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now())
>>>> 05-11-2015 19:00.173546
```

But I only want time: 19:00

Do you know how to do it? Is there a function for that?

Comment: print(datetime.datetime.now().time())

Comment: @jeffcarey that worked. Thanks

Comment: Also check out time.localtime() in combination with time.strftime()

Comment: @jeffcarey AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'localtime'

Comment: datetime.time is not the same as time.time   - I beleive he refers to the time moudle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.time()` is equivalent to `datetime.time(hours=0, minute=0)`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.time()
datetime.time(0, 0)
>>> datetime.time(hour=0, minute=0)
datetime.time(0, 0)
```

[`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) is a module. [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) is a class. `datetime.time()` is an instance of that class created using the default hour, minute values (`0`,`0`) e.g., to create [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) object that corresponds to `19:00` instead, you could use `datetime.time(19, 0)`.

To print only time for an existing [`datettime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) or [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) instance, you could use [`%H:%M` time format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print("{:%H:%M}".format(current_time))
08:40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
time = date_time.time()

# date_time is a datetime object tuple of year, month, day, hour, minnute, second, ms 
# to access the time portion, simply call the time() function, which will return a tuple of only the hour, minue, second portion

# printing the time will give timestamp representation, but the object is actually of type datetime.time
```

Comment: Cool: 19:17:45.922373 What means'.922373'?

Comment: pretty sure they are microseconds

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
from datetime import datetime;

t = datetime.now();
print '%d-%d' % (t.hour, t.minute);
#prints 19:17
```

Comment: Yes, same time zone :)